# Limit on X509v3 Subject Alternative Name DNSname length

Tags: x509, certificate

I have been searching through RFC 5280, 1034, and 1123 trying to figure out what a max string length is, but I can't find it.  I'm wondering if any of you happen to know.

For those of you who know about X509v3 certificates, you know that you can include a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) in the cert.  There are different types of SANs: email address, dns name, directory name, etc.

I'm adding SANs of type DNSName to my certificates and I cannot figure out what the maximum length is for SANs of type DNSName.

Do any of you know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RFC 5280 specifies 1..MAX GeneralNames for SubjectAltName in 4.2.1.6:

```
SubjectAltName ::= GeneralNames
GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName
```

In Appendix B. it states that

> The construct "SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF" appears in several ASN.1
>      constructs.  A valid ASN.1 sequence will have zero or more entries.
>      The SIZE (1..MAX) construct constrains the sequence to have at least
>      one entry.  MAX indicates that the upper bound is unspecified.
>      Implementations are free to choose an upper bound that suits their
>      environment.

which means that the limit will be implementation dependent. [This CA](https://reseller.certifyid.com/Home/Unified) will sign certs with 150 alternate names, so presumably *something* will work with that many.

Comment: This would explain why I couldn't find it in the specs: it's implementation-dependent.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the macOS Certificate Assistant, a SubjectAltNames field of length 273 caused the certificate creation so silently fail. After having reduced to a length of 203, it worked. Makes me assume the magic limit may be at something around 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when I tried it it limits to 36 characters for a single DNS name inside the Subj Alt Name

When I created the self signed cert using openssl we used this config

```
[req_ext]                              
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1= *.somedomain.com
DNS.2= x111us-somedomain-com-1888222111.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

When viewed from the browser it shows

```
Extension: Subject Alternative Name (2.5.29.17)
Critical: NO
DNS Name: *.test.com
DNS Name: x111us-somedomain-com-1851944707.us-
```

there are some missing chars on the 2nd DNS x111us-somedomain-com-1851944707.us-(some missing chars here***)